Session Cookie in Blazor Interactive Rendermode and individual Identity with Default Web APP
I made a Blazor 8 Web app project with Interactive Server, individual Identity, per page/component.

so I just did debug it

registered one user

and login

close the tab or close the web browser each time

but the session cookie is still alive


Why does Blazor work like this, in default mode?
Even though I tried to put some more options in 'program.cs' it is not changed at all.
I want the session cookie to expire when I close the tab or the web browser. And Shouldn't it be the default practice like that?

Some person replied to use CircuitHandler, but I am curious why Identity itself can't support this?
or Am I lost my way to know how to use it rightly?
Automatic Logout On Close Tab/Browser - Blazor Server Side
also its github source is too outdated.

You could achieve this by check a configuration in visual studio.
Tools-Options-Debugging-General-"Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET". 

Then when restart debugging, it will use a new instance of browser.

Thank you for the reply. It seems to work like secret mode. But it could not be used in production.

@sayditto Do you want the browser to clear auth cookie when user only close the tab? That seems not a good idea.

Unfortunately, that is exactly what I want to serve the way on my WebAPP, intentionally. If you have spare time, could you let me know why you commented, this is not a good idea?
